# Converting simple Python code into a Java method

Tags: java, python

I found a code snippet that gives me exactly what I want in a automated tournament bracket generator: AN ARRAY.

There is an issue. I do not read nor write python, but I am proficient (enough) in Java.
I don't know if this is bad stack overflow etiquette, but I am asking for someone to assist in the conversion of this code to a Java method.

```py
def CBseed( n ):
    #returns list of n in standard tournament seed order
    #Note that n need not be a power of 2 - 'byes' are returned as zero
    ol = [1]
    for i in range( int(ceil( log(n) / log(2) ) )):
        l = 2*len(ol) + 1
        ol = [e if e <= n else 0 for s in [[el, l-el] for el in ol] for e in s]
    return ol
```

Which returns a nice

```py
2 [1, 2] #seed 1 plays seed 2
3 [1, 0, 2, 3] #seed 1 gets a 'by' game and seed 2 plays seed 3
4 [1, 4, 2, 3] #ETC.
5 [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 3, 0]
6 [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 3, 6]
7 [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6]
8 [1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6]
#and so on and so forth till this
31 [1, 0, 16, 17, 8, 25, 9, 24, 4, 29, 13, 20, 5, 28, 12, 21, 2, 31, 15, 18, 7, 26, 10, 23, 3, 30, 14, 19, 6, 27, 11, 22]
32 [1, 32, 16, 17, 8, 25, 9, 24, 4, 29, 13, 20, 5, 28, 12, 21, 2, 31, 15, 18, 7, 26, 10, 23, 3, 30, 14, 19, 6, 27, 11, 22]
```

So the array kind of increments in twos, with every two being one game.

Comment: If you can code in Java, then why can't you read this Python? It contains assignment, `for in` loop, `range()`, `int()` cast, `log()`, `len`, `if else`, and a return.

Comment: I'm guessing the second to last line is throwing him off.  Rest is pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Well, `[e if e <= n else 0 for s in [[el, l-el] for el in ol] for e in s]` is somewhat convoluted for someone who's not fluent in Python.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I have no idea how to read Python. Although the power in this little of code makes me want to read up on it

Comment: @MohammadS. Yes, exactly

Comment: That list comprehension is unnecessarily convoluted. Couldn't it just be `[e if e <= n else 0 for el in ol for e in (el, l-el)]`? And I'm not sure that `for` loop is needed.

Comment: +1 This kind of question is common for comparative language courses or jobs that require multiple core languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct translation would be something like:

```
public static List<Integer> cbSeed(int n) {
    List<Integer> ol = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ol.add(1);

    int max = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        int l = 2 * ol.size() + 1;

        List<Integer> newOl = new ArrayList<Integer>(ol.size() * 2);
        for (int el : ol) {
            int e = el;
            newOl.add(e <= n ? e : 0);

            e = l - el;
            newOl.add(e <= n ? e : 0);
        }

        ol = newOl;
    }

    return ol;
}
```

As you can see Java is more verbose :)

---

You can see that this produces identical results as the Python function:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++)
    System.out.println(i + "\t" + cbSeed(i));
```

```
2   [1, 2]
3   [1, 0, 2, 3]
4   [1, 4, 2, 3]
5   [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 3, 0]
6   [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 3, 6]
7   [1, 0, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6]
8   [1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 7, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Aw, you beat me to it.  Your answer looks nicer so +1.  This link may help if anyone wants to understand the `for in` in Python: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for! I should look into python as well!!